# Путь в php

Tags: include, php

Доброго времени суток.
В общем столкнулся с такой проблемой. 
Есть файл `index.php` в корневом каталоге, следующего содержания.

```
define('rootpath',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/');
include(rootpath."system/load.php");
if($_GET['module'])
{
    Module::run($_GET['module']);
}else {
$twig->display('index.tpl');
}
```

если `url` содержит `$_GET['module']` то запускаем соответственно класс. Который в свою очередь содержит простой инклуд из пути `/module/$_GET['module']/index.php`
Но вот в чем проблема. Если у нас в корневом каталоге `$twig->display()` отображает без проблем, то при загрузке `/module/$_GET['module']/index.php` в котором содержится так же `$twig->display()` он его уже не видит.

```
Call to a member function display() on a non-object
```

хотя страница просто инклудится в родительскую где `$twig` по умолчанию объявлен в /`system/load.php`

Или я чего не понимаю, или подскажите как исправить это недоразумение....

Пытался объявить и в /module/$_GET['module']/index.php загрузку /system/load.php, но и это не помогло...

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не вызвана ли эта проблема опять mod_rewrite-ом?

Comment: @void, не=) в этот раз я уже умнее)) пока без него

Comment: Т.е. физическое расположение файлов совпадает с путями в URL. Тогда 2 вопроса: что конкретно выполняет метод **run** и лежит ли папка **module** в корне сайта?

Comment: @void, module лежит в корне сайта.
run на данном этапе, получает GET, проверяет есть ли такая папка в module и инклудит index.php из него. т.е include_once ("module/$_GET[module]/index.php");
пока без всякой магии

Comment: Я отвечу на скорую руку, а то мне по делам идти. Попробуйте использовать define для полного пути до load.php и объявление этого вынесите в какую-нибудь globvars.php, которая будет вставляться в index.php. У вас 100 процентов теряется где-то относительность пути до инклуда.

Comment: @Александр Маслов, И вообще, замените include на require. Так что если увидите FATAL ERROR, то это повод внимательно просмотреть пути.

Comment: @void, да, уже заменил.
но проблема в классе... потому как прямым запросом в index.php что в корне, все отображает и работает, а через класс не хочет...

Comment: вот мой грубый класс, ничего в нем не колдовал, сейчас главное чтоб корректно выводил:

class Module {
 
private $path = "module/";
 
 public function __construct($module)
 {
  if(is_dir($this->path.$module.'/'))
  {
   return $this->display($module);
  } else {
   echo "false";
  }
 }
 
 public function display($module)
 {
  require('module/'.$module.'/index.php');
 }
 
}

Теперь вызываю без run прямиком напрямую. Так не находит display()/ а если тоже самое без модуля в корне index.php то все прекрасно. Не понимаю разницы...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменная `$twig` создается в глобальном пространстве, файл модуля подключается вызовом статичного метода `Module::run`, в котором данной переменной нету, соответственно скрипт валится так как дальше идет попытка вызова метода `display` на не инициализированной переменной. Можно в методе `Module::run` добавить `global $twig`, но лучше переписать без использования глобальных переменных.

PS. `/module/$_GET['module']/index.php` - жесть.

Comment: Да знаю что жесть, говорю пока без магии все=)
О, а это уже мысль! А поподробнее, чтобы без глобалок? 
Да, с - global $twig; работает. Зациклился на путях, что совсем забыл про global :\ не в ту сторону копал...

Answer (score 0):

Может

```
require('/module/'.$module.'/index.php');
```

вместо

```
require('module/'.$module.'/index.php');
```

?

Comment: не туда копали мы с тобой=) ответ выше